# Realm Studio is behaving busy. I am authenticated but the app doesn't progress past this initial window. What should I Do?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

[image]

I have been at this for a while. I am trying to create a local Real Object Sever, however, Realm Studio doesn't advance past this window. 
My Connection is 100% okay. How can I fix this, and is there another way that I can create Realms?

Comment: Hi Chris. I see you upgraded to version 1.14.0, do you still get the error with the latest version of Realm Studio?

Comment: Hi again Chris - I would love to hear if you're still getting this on the latest version of Realm Studio?

Comment: Yes I am, Ive tried the most recent update and im still not able to access realm studio. Im using a local real object server